# Counting the number of sales for each date in a date range, postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a row for each sale of a product.  These rows include a date.  I want to know the number of products sold for each distinct day in a range (user specifies the begin and end dates.)  There is a distinct row for each sale, so on days where several products were sold, several rows with this date exist.  I want to count the number of these rows, with the same date.  How might this be done efficiently in postgresql?

Example

```
2015-01-02: 0
2015-01-03: 7
2015-01-04: 2
```

Comment: Are these dates postgresql `datetimes` or `varchars`?

Comment: @dal102 - They are varchars (unavoidable in this case)

Comment: I added information to handle either case to my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the date column is stored as a `datetime`, something like this should get you in the right direction:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP sales.date) as day, COUNT(*)
FROM sales
WHERE day >= start and <= end
GROUP BY day;
```

where `start` and `end` are filled in by the user.

More documentation for postgres's date features found here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html

---

If they are *not* `datetime`, you can use the `to_date` function with the appropriate format string to convert to datetime and the use the solution above:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', to_date('2015-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html